# How to declare more than one column name using Xcelite library

Tags: java, excel

I'm deserializing a Java bean from several Excel spreadsheets using [Xcelite](http://www.xcelite.io), and It has an attribute which can match more than one column name.

This is my Java Bean

```
    import com.ebay.xcelite.annotations.Column;

    public class User {
    
       @Column(name = "User") 
       private String username;
    
       @Column(name = "Email") 
       private String email;    
    }
```

I have to deserialize the same object using another spreadsheet which uses `User` column name instead of `Login`.

I could use the solution below, however I'd like to know whether is there a better approach ?

```java
    public class User {
    
       @Column(name = "User") 
       private String username;

       @Column(name = "Login") 
       private String login;
    
       @Column(name = "Email") 
       private String email;   

       public String getUsername() {
          return username != null ? username : login;  
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are currently no provisions for that.

Xcelite is focused on reading from **one** sheet at a time, and knows nothing about applying a mapping to multiple sheets.

As you may have noticed, the original Xcelite code has been abandoned by Ebay. I maintain [a fork](https://github.com/xcelite-io/xcelite), you are more than welcome to help out by speccing a mapping over multiple sheets. I can see the merit of what you are trying to do.